# My password reset script keeps telling me to fill in all fields

Tags: php

I've been trying to remove the need of entering the username when you want to reset the password to only enter the email. I can't understand what the difference is here because I've removed the username part in the html and then it tells me that I have to fill in all the fields even though I don't need the username field, and if I add it back then it works as it should even though my php code doesn't require the need of username.

**old reset form**

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <form method="POST">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Forgot Password ?</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Enter your user name below.</p>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="User Name" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" autocomplete="off" required>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Enter your e-mail address below.</p>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" autocomplete="off" required>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
                    <button id="reset" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Reset</button>
                    <hr>
                    <div id="result"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**New reset form**

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" class="modal fade">
            <form method="POST">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Forgot Password ?</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Enter your e-mail address below.</p>
                            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" autocomplete="off" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
                            <button id="reset" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Reset</button>

                            <hr>
                            <div id="result"><?php print_r($_POST)?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'reset') {

        if(isset($_POST['email'])
            && is_string($_POST['email'])
            && !empty($_POST['email'])) {

            if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                $email = $_POST['email'];

                $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserEmail = :UserEmail');
                $stmt->execute(array(':UserEmail' => $email));

                if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                    $new_password = substr(md5(rand(1,100000)), 0, 8);

                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE users SET UserPassword = :UserPassword WHERE UserEmail = :UserEmail');
                    $stmt->execute(array(':UserPassword' => md5($new_password), ':UserEmail' => $email));

                    $subject = 'Password recovery';
                    $txt = 'Your account password has been reset.';
                    $txt .= 'Your new account password is: '.$new_password.'';
                    $headers = "From: ".$RecoveryEmail."" . "\r\n" .
                    "CC: ".$RecoveryEmail."";

                    mail($email,$subject,$txt,$headers);
                } else {
                    echo('User with these credentials does not exist.');
                }
            } else {
                echo('The entered E-mail is invalid.');
            }
        } else {
            echo('Fill all fields correctly.');
        }
    }
```

Comment: **DON'T** use md5 for passwords. it's been insecure **for years**. use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` instead.

Comment: Then your IF is failing one of the tests.

Comment: Where do you set/pass `$_POST['action']` ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't understand how it can fail when It's filled out correctly.

Comment: @MacroMan In another file called responds.php

Comment: so we need to see that code too - you're not passing that properly. When you hit that submit button, it will only send what is in the form. The form doesn't contain the value for `$_POST['action']` so it isn't being set.

Comment: Amend the test to `if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {` does it work then?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Still saying Fill all fields correctly

Comment: From manual _empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false` So `isset()` and `!empty()` are overkill

Comment: Ok so do a `print_r($_POST)` and see what is actually in `$_POST`

Comment: You don't have any input field which is named `action`

Comment: @RiggsFolly it outputs Array ( [email] => example@yahoo.com)

Comment: @apokryfos Oh yes. My mistake. And just to prove it he does not have an action occurance

Comment: @jake ..... well now you know what the problem is ..... No `action` in `$_POST`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Not really? is it the input field?

Comment: But there is NO `[action] => reset` in `$_POST` so it fails the first IF test

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually this code should not be printing anything unless there's an extra `{` added in the question which does not exist in the actual code. I do suspect there is a copy/paste error going on here.

Comment: Possibly because `<button id="reset" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Reset</button>` does not have a `name="action"` and come to that it is not `type="submit"` so how are you actually submitting this form? _javascript_??

Comment: No its not any clearer. I am assuming you have more than one form in this process flow and you are expecting some other data like `password` to be in the `$_POST array from the previous page/form. But it will not be